# What does the person looking from the point of the image which is behind see?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

In a plane mirror, the image of an object is virtual and is behind the image of another object. What does the observer looking from the point of the image which is behind see?

Comment: Nothing. No light from the object reaches that observer since they're behind a mirror that reflects all the light incident upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a one way mirror, then an observer in the apparent position of the behind image will not see the original objects directly. If they look towards the behind object, they will only see the back of the mirror surface, or whatever is between that observer and the mirror back surface.

If, however, the mirror is one way, for example, a smooth window in a lit room while it is dark night outside then it will behave like a mirror as seen by the people inside the room, but as a window as seen by the observers outside. In this case the observer in the position of the behind image will, if they look in the direction of the behind object, see the object which makes the front image. He/she could see the behind object through another reflector that is appropriately angled or positioned with respect to the observer vs the behind object.